# Calling a php function inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm fairly new in PHP and javaScript and need to do something that seems very simple but is taking too long. I have this function ]
`
public function engenhariaDuplicada($form_tabela, $form){

```
    $Composicao = $form->formArray['campos']['geral']['D074_D001_Id_Composicao']['value'];
    $Principal = $form->formArray['campos']['geral']['D074_D001_Id']['value'];
$sql = "select * from D074 where D074_D001_Id_Composicao = '{$Composicao}' 
            and D074_D001_Id = '{$Principal}'";
$conjuntoDados = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($conjuntoDados) > 0){
    $confirmacao = 0;
    echo "<script>
        if(confirm('Este produto já existe. Deseja incluir mesmo assim?')){
            CALL A PHP FUNCTION
        }
    </script>";
    return true;
}
```

}
`
I just need to call a function which is in a file called CAD052.php.
Can someone give me some pointers ?

Thankyou all !

I've tried this and it didn't work. I know I'm supposed to use jquery. I just need some directions.

Comment: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)

Comment: Did you try to use Ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a request to the PHP page from the JS.
Also, you should use `mysqli` and stmt for security reasons.